# Character encoding issue with Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, character-encoding

I migrated a wordpress website from my test server to a live server. Unfortunately, a lot of black diamonds with white question marks in it appeared on the new server.

[This](http://www.nmo-internal.com/kunsthandel-freller/de/startseite/) is the testserver and [this](http://antikhaus.at/de/startseite/) is the live-server. If you scroll down a bit, you will notice the black diamonds with the question marks where the umlauts "ä", "ö" and "ü", respecitvely should be displayed. 
I realized that as soon as I change the browser encoding from "unicode" to "western", everything seems fine.

Below you can see an image of the database tables. The database has a collation of "latin1_swedish_ci".

[image]

What can I do to display the correct characters?

Comment: You need change database collation to utf8mb4_general_ci, this might not retroactively fix your issue but future data will be encoded properly.

Comment: Well thanks, and is there no way to change the current data to the right format?

Comment: I believe your data is already encoded, so I can't think of any way to convert the encodings. You might have to enter the data manually. Sorry :(

Comment: Yasin, if I output a MySQL Dump in phpMyAdmin and open it with Notepad++, I could change the character encoding, right? If yes, which encoding should I use? If that doesn't work, what should I enter manually? Sorry for all the questions ;)

Comment: Yes you can dump the data and edit the ?? marks with the right characters and import the data back to mysql. Just so you are clear, this is not the same as changing the encoding. The encoding is determined by the database based on your database collation.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that the characters are correctly displayed in my Notepad++. UTF-8 without BOM is set as encoding. I'm stuck now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is to add

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

to the header.php file. This provides the correct character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for the same throughout the internet. Finally found a working solution.

I tried method 1 listed on the below website and it works like charm.

Just changed these two lines from `wp-config.php`:

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

with

`//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); //define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

Here is the article link: https://samacharpedia.com/fix-strange-character-encoding-issue-wordpress-post-content/